# ImportError: No module named models?

Tags: django, importerror

I am using Django and I keep receiving this error for my group app, I have checked all my import settings and everything is fine. My registration and profile apps run smoothly but why is this app giving me an ImportError for models?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 219, in execute
    self.validate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 249, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 36, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 146, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 64, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 78, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/gladiator/django_projects/classes/groups/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    from groups.shortcuts import build_filename
  File "/home/gladiator/django_projects/classes/groups/groups.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "/home/gladiator/django_projects/classes/groups/decorators.py", line 2, in <module>
    from groups.models import Group, GroupMember
ImportError: No module named models
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it thinks that you're referring to the `groups.py` in the same directory. [Enable absolute imports](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/).

Comment: should i rather just change the name of groups.py, i have it in a views folder since i have two views groups.py and pages.py?

Comment: If you need to support earlier versions of Python then you will have to.

Comment: I have changed the file name but it seems to still  be recognizing a groups.py which is no longer there since i changed the name.

Comment: Did you remember to erase the compiled bytecode file (`groups.pyc`) as well?

Comment: Ahhhhh....i had moved the groups.py to the view folder i created but forget to also move the groups.pyc file as well. I deleted it and all works fine. Thanks, dude you are really good!!!

Answer (score 3):

I hade the same problem. The solution was as simple as

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

[hinted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6773047/194515) by [Ignacio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20862/ignacio-vazquez-abrams)

Comment: Very underrated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but does your models.py file import groups or decorators? If so, you have a circular dependency. You'll need to move the imports in one of the files into the function level.

Comment: A problematic circular import would result in a `NameError`, not a `ImportError`.